# how to duplicate a button via script?

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following code:

```
public GameObject characterButtonPrefab;
public GameObject characterButtonContainer;
public GameObject optionsContainer;

public GameObject[] charButtons;
private int charButtonsIndex = 0;
private Text[] cBT;
private string[] buttonTexts = new string[] {"Strength 5", "Agility 5", "Intelligence 5", "Charisma 5", "Diplomacy 5" };

private void Start()
{
    LevelIsOver = false;
    IsNextWave = false;
    //Time.timeScale = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < charButtons.Length; i++)
    {
        int size = charButtons.Length;
        cBT = new Text[size];
        GameObject container = (GameObject)Instantiate(characterButtonPrefab);
        container.transform.SetParent(characterButtonContainer.transform, false);
        cBT[i] = characterButtonPrefab.transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        cBT[i].text = buttonTexts[Random.Range(0, buttonTexts.Length)];
        charButtonsIndex++;
    }

    //if (charButtons.Length > 0)
    //{
    //    GameObject currentChar = (GameObject)Instantiate(characterButtonPrefab);
    //    currentChar.transform.SetParent(optionsContainer.transform, false);
    //    currentChar.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
    //    currentChar.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => CharacterSelection());
    //}
}
```

I declared the size of array to 20 in the inspector and everything work fine. The buttons are created and text changed.
The question is how do I duplicate the first button in that array to another panel ? I have searched the internet  but nothing found about this.

I have tried this:

```
GameObject currentChar = (GameObject)Instantiate(charButtons[0]);
     currentChar.transform.SetParent(optionsContainer.transform, false);
     currentChar.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
     currentChar.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => CharacterSelection());
 }
```

But I get ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.

Comment: Why you need to duplicate the first button, is it different from others, can't you just instantiate new button with your `CharacterButtonPrefab`??

Comment: The error message "The Object you want to instantiate is null" seems pretty self-explanatory to me. You seem to do this before you put the button into the button array. Or you have that code in a different object with a different charButtons array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have set the length of the `charButtons` in the inspector to 20, the default value of each element is `null`. You have to fill this array with instantiated buttons:

```
 int size = charButtons.Length;
 cBT = new Text[size];

 for (int i = 0; i < charButtons.Length; i++)
 {
     charButtons[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(characterButtonPrefab);
     charButtons[i].transform.SetParent(characterButtonContainer.transform, false);
     cBT[i] = characterButtonPrefab.transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
     cBT[i].text = buttonTexts[Random.Range(0, buttonTexts.Length)];
     charButtonsIndex++;
 }

 if (charButtons.Length > 0)
 {
     GameObject currentChar = Instantiate(charButtons[0]);
     currentChar.transform.SetParent(optionsContainer.transform, false);
     currentChar.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
     currentChar.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(CharacterSelection );
 }
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer I applied and it work. Thanks